# Subtracting large integers

Tags: javascript

So.  I'm trying to subtract large integers.  76561198060995608 - 76561197960265728 = 100729880 type numbers.  (I'm converting a 64 bit to a 32 bit)  Vbscript and JS both give 100729888.

I would love to be able to do it in vbscript, but I'm either doing something wrong with cdbl (returns 100729888) or ccur (Overflow: 'ccur' error happens) or it can't be done the way I'm trying.

I've tried implementing JS libraries (bignum, bignumber) and they also haven't returned the correct number, again, maybe because of my error.  [BigNumber](http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber) returns 100729890.

Big number code as follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            var x = new BigNumber(76561198060995608).subtract(new BigNumber(76561197960265728))
            alert(x)
        })
```

So...what am I doing wrong?  Am I making a stupid mistake?  I don't feel like this should take the 6+ hours it's taken me so far.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you try

```
new BigNumber(76561198060995608)
```

you're still relying on the JavaScript runtime to parse and represent that number *before* it calls the "BigNumber" constructor. I'm pretty sure you can pass a string to that constructor:

```
new BigNumber("76561198060995608")
```

and that should give you a fighting chance.